# Считать число из файла и записать его в переменную на Си

Tags: c

Есть файл, который содержит целое число и больше ничего, например, 312567. Пытаюсь считать из него данные и записать в переменную а для дальнейшего использования - ничего не получается,- уже несколько часов разные варианты использую. Может кто-то поможет с работающим примером на С, т.к. есть другой код на С, который это значение будет использовать? Буду рад помощи.

Код такой:

```
#include <stdio.h> // библиотека для вывода на экран
int main(void)
{
        int a;
        FILE *k = fopen("/home/pi/c/file1.txt", "r"); // файл из которого читаем значение
        fscanf(k,"%d%",a);
        fclose(k);
        printf("значение %d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: Вы наверное забыли ваш код добавить в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил то, что написал, но не работает почему-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fscanf(k,"%d",&a);
```

Надо указывать **адрес**, куда записывать значение...
Надеюсь, что у вас в вопросе `%` после `%d` - просто очепятка...

Comment: Спасибо! заработало!

Comment: Рад за вас :) И еще - не путайте цифру и число. Я серьезно, потому что именно *цифру* читать надо было бы по-другому. Если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый.

Comment: А, цифра - это один символ, понял.